# Are these probabilities orthogonal?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Given $p\in (0,1)$ we define a Borel probability $\mu_p$ in the interval $[0,1]$.

We assign $\mu_p([0,1/2))=1-p$ and $\mu_p([1/2,1))=p$. We iterate this process by diving each interval in two and giving $(1-p)$ of the measure of the previous interval to the first side and $p$ of the measure of the previous interval to the second side. In this fashion we have $\mu_p([0,1/4))=(1-p)^2$, $\mu_p([1/4,1/2))=(1-p)p=\mu_p([1/2,3/4))$, $\mu_p([3/4,1))=p^2$, and so on and so forth. This defines a Borel measure because the dyadic intervals are a generator of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I'm asked whether these probabilitites are continuous ($\mu_p({x})=0\;\forall x\in[0,1)$) and whether, given $p\neq q$, $\mu_p\perp\mu_q$ (there's a Borel-measurable set $A$ such that $\mu_p(A)=0$ and $\mu_q(A^{\mathsf{c}})=0$).

I figured out the first part in the following way. Let $x\in[0,1)$. For every $n\in\mathbf{N}\;\exists\; 0\leq j\leq 2^n-1$ such that $x\in[j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n})$, and we have

\begin{equation}
\mu_p({x})\leq\mu_p([j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n}))\leq max\{p^n, (1-p)^n\}\xrightarrow{\: n \to \infty \: }0
\end{equation}

Now, I'm really clueless for the second part. It seems like the probabilities shouldn't be orthogonal, as all intervals have positive probability for both probabilities and all singletons have probability $0$ for both probabilities. But how can we be sure that there isn't a strange collection of points concentrating all the measure for $p$ and no measure for $q$? Or, alternatively, how can we find such a collection?

Comment: Hint: you can use the strong law of large numbers to construct your set $A$.

Comment: @kimchilover could you develop a bit more? I'm not really getting it

Comment: You've shown the $\mu_p$ are continuous, so the set of $x\in[0,1]$ for which $x$ has a unique  binary expansion $x=\sum_n x_n2^{-n}$ has $\mu_p$ measure $1$.  So $\mu_p$ pushes forward to a measure on binary sequence space.  What is that measure?

Comment: @kimchilover sorry but I'm completely lost in here. I don't see how $\mu_p$ being continuous implies that the set with unique binary expansion has measure $1$, I don't see why the push-forward measure in the binary sequence space is relevant and also I don't see where the law of large numbers is to be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another description of the measure $\mu_p$:  Pick an iid sequence of bits $x_1,x_2,...$, with $P[x_i=1] = p$ and $P[x_i=0]=1-p$, and form the sum $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i 2^{-i}$.  Then $x$ has probability measure $\mu_p$.
(The interval $[0,1/2)$ has probability $1-p$ and the interval $[1/2,1]$ has probability $p$, corresponding to $x_1=0$ and $x_1=1$, etc.)

The strong law of large numbers tells us that
$$P\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}n = p\right] = 1.$$
You should be able to guess what the set $A$ is, and fill in the remaining details.

Comment: Thank you! So the $X$ such that that limit is $p$ have measure $\mu_p$ $1$, but they have measure $\mu_q$ $0$ (becasue here the set of $X$ such that the limit is $q$ has measure $1$) (?)

Comment: If $A_r$ means the numbers whose digit average is $r$, then yes, $\mu_p(A_p)=1$ and, because $\mu_p([0,1])=1$, we have  $\mu_p(A_q)=0$.